# How to dark mode across all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get it right?

Every time I change to a different page or I refresh it switches back to a light theme in my site:

https://github.com/elasticalva/elasticalva.github.io

This is my button (root/_includes/navigation.html):

```
<li><div id="btn-light-dark"></div></li>
```

This is my CSS (root/_sass/_layout.scss):

```
body {
    background-color: #edf2f7;
    color: #333333;
}

.oscuro {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #edf2f7;
}

#btn-light-dark::after {
  content: '';
}

body.oscuro #btn-light-dark::after {
  content: '';
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
      color:#333333;
      background:#edf2f7
  }}
```

And this is my JS (root/assets/dark.js):

```
const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
    const btnElem = document.querySelector(btn);
  
    const setText = () => {
      const text = document.body.classList.contains('oscuro') ? '' : '☀️';
      btnElem.textContent = text;
    }
  
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('oscuro');
        setText();
      }
    });
  
    setText();
  
  }
  
  btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");
```

And it gives me this many errors:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null*

- *at setText (dark.js:5)*
- *at btnDarkLight (dark.js:16)*
- *at dark.js:20*

It should be simple but I don't get it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use localStorage to keep state. So it will save your changes after refreshing or closing tab

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS to put the current theme mode in the 'localstorage' which is kept across pages and sessions, use it like this:

```
// set dark mode
localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');

// set light mode
localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');

// check if darkmode:
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == 'dark') {

}
```

And then you can just check the current theme everytime you load the page

Comment: It won't work for me... I've tried but it not holds the dark theme state. DKW

Comment: Look up how you can find the localstorage items in the inspector manually, so you are sure if it actually stores it or not

Comment: I think it won´t store it. Or load it.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried like this but isn´t storing or loading the theme:

```
  const btnDarkLight = (btn) => {
    const btnElem = document.querySelector(btn);
  
    const setText = () => {
      const text = document.body.classList.contains('oscuro') ? '' : '☀️';
      btnElem.textContent = text;
    }
  
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches(btn)) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('oscuro');
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "oscuro");
        setText();
      }
    });
  
    setText();
  
  }
  
  btnDarkLight("#btn-light-dark");




window.onload = checkTheme();

function checkTheme() {
    const localStorageTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

    if (localStorageTheme !== null && localStorageTheme === "oscuro") {
        // set the theme of body
        document.body.className = localStorageTheme;
    }
}
```